# The number of $\langle x, e_k\rangle$ such that $| \langle x, e_k\rangle | > 1/m$ is less than $m^2 ||x||^2.$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

I am self studying Kreyszig book of functional analysis and couldn't solve following problem which is 8 th of section 3.4 
Problem is

Show that an element $x$ of an inner product space $X$ cannot have too many Fourier coefficients $\langle  x, e_k\rangle$ which are big, $\langle  e_k\rangle$ is orthonormal sequence. Precisely, show that number $ n_m $ of $\langle  x, e_k\rangle$ such that $| \langle  x, e_k\rangle | > 1/m$ must satisfy $ n_m <  m^2  ||x||^2.$

I tried using Bessel's inequality but I don't know how to exactly get $ n_m <  m^2  ||x||^2.$

Comment: @Thomas Shellby I tried using Bessel inequality

Comment: @ Thomas Shellby but I dont know how to exactly get $ n_m $ <  $ m^2 $  $ ||x||^2 $

Comment: Use $\sum_{k}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2 \le \|x\|^2$ as a starting point. Then reduce the sum to those for which $|\langle x,e_k\rangle| > 1/m$.

Comment: So, you know that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\le\|x\|^2$. Now, assume that, e.g., the first $K$ summands are greater than $\frac 1{m^2}$. What follows from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_m=\{e_k\mid\frac1m\lt |\langle x,e_k\rangle |\} $. Assume we have   $n_m$ distinct elements in $S_m $, say $e_{l_1},\ldots,e_{l_{n_m}} $. Then $$\frac {n_m}{m^2}\lt \sum_{k=1}^{n_m} |\langle x,e_{l_k}\rangle |^2\leq \|x\|^2.$$

Comment: @ Thomas Shellby Thanks

Comment: The logic is correct but I think the indexing within the sum is not.  The sum as written picks up all indices $\leq n_m$, whether or not the index is within $S_m$.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you. I have changed the indexing.